# Comparing the Heart and Luchot

Tags: commentaries, parashat-ki-tisa, mishlei

I was reading in Mishlei ([3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), 7:3) the other day and noticed that our hearts are sometimes compared to tablets, and that on it the Words of HaShem should be inscribed. This reminded me of Yirmiyahu who states that HaShem will inscribe His Words upon our hearts.

The only tablets I know of which were (physically) inscribed are the stone tablets with the Aseret HaDevarim on them.

Are there any commentaries which link the inscribing of the heart with the Luchot HaBrit?

Comment: Try taking a look at this essay I wrote and see if it helps: https://www.academia.edu/7237484/Squared_vs_Rounded_Tablets

Comment: Rb Moshe Shapiro said the reason it is traditional in shuls for the luchos on the aron hakodesh to be rounded is so they should look like a heart. (As per the passuk you quote from Yirmiyahu.)

Comment: That doesn't look like a heart at all? Just like those valentine thingy-s.

Comment: The essay of RC HaQoton says the "heart-shaped" reason in the name of R' Chaim Friedlander. My objection still stands...

Comment: Added sources in Mishlei. The source text there is the clearest answer to the _original question_ that I've seen!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many. One good example is taken from Rabbi Tzadok HaKohen of Lublin in Sefer Pri Tzaddik on parshat Tetzaveh 5:1 which says:

> איתא (שבת קיט :) כל המתפלל בערב שבת ואומר ויכולו ובקידוש אנו מוסיפין תיבות ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי ולהבין שייכות תיבות אלו לקידוש היום הגם שיש רמז בר"ת יום הששי ויכולו השמים לשם הוי"ה כידוע יש להבין ענין הרמז בתיבות אלו דייקא. גם שייכות תיבות ויהי ערב וגו'. אמנם בשים לב על סדר הבריאה של ו' ימי המעשה שלאחר שנאמר בהם וירא אלהים כי טוב כ' ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר ולכאורה מה שייכות הערב שקודם אור היום לגמר בראית היום ויובן זה עד"ש (שם עז :) כברייתו של עולם דברישא חשוכא והדר נהורא והיינו על פי מ"ש בזוהר הקדוש פ' זו (קפד א) דלית נהורא אלא ההוא דנפיק מגו חשוכא והיינו שבכל יום מששת ימי המעשה יש הארת קדושה ממדה אחת מז' תחתונות שנקרא בוקר וזלעו"ז יש בו גם מבחינת ההיפך שנקרא ערב שמסתיר הקדושה ודייקא לאחר שנתגלה מדת הקדושה כי טוב הוא נתברר בזה בחינת הערב שמקודם לו שנעשה לו הויה שהיה סיבה שעל ידי זה נתגלה בחינת הבוקר שלו כי טוב. עד בריאת יום הששי שכנגד יסוד שבקדושה והיינו בריאת אדם הראשון שהוא תכלית מכוון הבריאה ונאמר אשר עשה האלהים את האדם ישר והיינו שהוא יהיה צדיק יסוד עולם. ונגד מדה זו שם שדי שאמר לעולמו די (כמ"ש זח"ג יא ב) והיינו שיש די באלהותו לכל בריה שנגמר תכלית מכוון הבריאה ליקח מהם ההכרה באלוהותו ית' ועל זה רמזו (סנהדרין לח :) דאדם הראשון מושך בערלתו היה והיינו שנברא מהול ועל ידי הקלקול נתהוה מסך הערלה וההסתר בכל הדורות עד שנצרך להתעצם בנפשו להעביר את מסך הערלה ועל ידי זה יהיה בא לתכלית מכוון הקדושה בחינת צדיק יסוד עולם. והקלקול הזה נתהוה בשעה אחרונה של גמר יום הששי וכמו שאז"ל (שם) שבשעה י"ב נטרד מג"א והלך לו. ובפרדר"א (פ' יט) איתא ובין השמשות בע"ש גורש ויצא כו' והיינו ברגע אחרונה של גמר יום הששי כי הקב"ה יודע עתיו ורגעיו נכנס בו כחוט השערה (כמ"ש ב"ר פ' י) וקודם הכנסת יום השבת על אותה רגע ממש נאמר וירא אלהים את כל אשר עשה והנה טוה מאד ונדרש בוקר יום הששי שמערב זה נעשה הויה דייקא להארת בחינת יום הששי כנ"ל שמרמז על בחינת צדיק יסוד עולם. ואיתא בפרדר"א (ר"פ כ') שגורש ויצא מגן עדן וישב לו בהר המוריה ששער ג"ע סמוך להר המוריה כו' שנאמר לעבוד את האדמה אשר לוקח משם ע"ש והיינו עפמ"ש (ב"ר פ' טז) לעבדה ולשמרה אלו הקרבנות שזה היה מכוון הבריאה שיתקרב אליו ית' בעבודת הקודש וגם א' (שם פ' יד) וייצר גו' את האדם עפר מן האדמה ממקום כפרתו נברא המד"א מזבח אדמה (וכ"כ בפרדר"א) ומזה דרש לעבוד את האדמה אשר לוקח משם היינו אותו מקום מזבח אדמה שמשם לוקח שהיה ע"ז ראשית מחשבת הבריאה שלו ממקום כפרתו. והיינו שיהיה גם עתה עסק עבודתו כמו בג"ע לעבדה ולשמרה כנ"ל ע"י תיקון מעשיו לכפר הקלקול וזה היה דייקא בשעה אחרונה של בין השמשות שהוא זמן תוספת שבת שהוא קדושת האדם הממשיך על עצמו קדושת שבת באתערותא דיליה. **וכל זה מרומז בתיבות ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי כנ"ל שדייקא ע"י הערב והחשכות נעשה הכנה לבחינת יום הששי שהוא מדת צדיק יסוד עולם.** **וידוע מאמרם (שבת פח.) ה' דהששי שהתנה הקב"ה עם מע"ב שאם מקבלין ישראל התורה אתם מתקיימין והיינו שכל מע"ב תלויים עד ששי בסיון דמתן תורה והיינו כי אז נגמר שלימות התיקון כש"נ חרות על הלוחות חירות ממלאך המות (כמ"ש שמות רבה פ' מא) שהוא היצר הרע כמ"ש (ב"ב טז ) והגם שאז ג"כ היה הקלקול ונשתברו הלוחות הלא נאמר פסל לך שני לחת אבנים כראשונים וגו' כי גם עתה אמרו (פ"ו דאבות) מפ' זה שאין לך בן חורין אלא מי שעוסק בתלמוד תורה כי בודאי בשעת מתן תורה היה כמו בראשית הבריאה אשר עשה האלהים את האדם ישר כי בשעה ששמעו ישראל דיבור אנכי נתקע ת"ת בלבם (כמ"ש שהש"ר פ' ישקני) והיו בתכלית השלימות כי היה הלב רצוף תמיד ביראתו ואהבתו ית' ולא היו נצרכים ללוחות אבנים שהיו נחקקים כל הדברי תורה על לוח לבם ונעקר יצר הרע מלבם בדבור לא היה (כמש"ש) רק לאחר שאמרו דבר אתה עמנו ונשמעה חזר יצה"ר למקומו ואחר הקלקול ע"ז נאמר למשה רבינו ע"ה פסל לך שני לוחות אבנים והיינו שמעתה שנעשה לבם לב אבן בהכרח לפסול הלוחות אבנים ע"י מעשה אדם והיינו שע"י יגיעת האדם בתורה יזכה מעתה להיות נחקקים הדברי תורה גם על לב האבן וכמו שדרשו (עירובין נד.) עמה שנאמר לוחות אבן אם משים אדם עצמו את לחייו כאבן זו שאינה נמחית תלמודו מתקיים בידו. ועל זה רמזו (פ"ה דאבות) שחשבו בעשרה דברים שנבראו בע"ש בין השמשות הכתב והמכתב והלוחות ופי' מכתב הוא עט וחרט העושה חקיקה על האבן (וכן פירש"י בפסחים) והיינו ההכנה שעל ידי יגיעת האדם בדברי תורה להיותם נקלטים בלב כדי לתקן גם לב האבן. וזה נרמז באות ה' דהששי שהוא רומז לה' ראשונה של שם הוי"ה הרמוז בר"ת כנ"ל.** ורומז לבחינת בינה לבא לתקן את הקלקול ביתר שאת עדש"נ ולבבו יבין ושב ורפא לו. וזה נרמז דייקא בתיבות ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי שהוא הכנסת תוספת שבת מצד האדם דייקא לאהפכא חשוכא לנהורא ובדא אסתלק קב"ה ביקריה (וכמ"ש זוה"ק פ' זו) וכן איתא (זוה"ח בלק) ע"פ מאשר יקרת בעיני נכבדת וגו' שהוא מרמז על הבעל תשובה המתקן העבר ועז"א מאשר יקרת דאיהו מגרמיה אתיקר מעתה שמקודם הוא מזלזא ותועבה קמי קב"ה ובתר דתב אתייקר מגרמיה ע"ש. ועל ידי זה בעיני נכבדת כי ע"י שגרם במעשיו דאסתלק קב"ה לעילא ואתייקר ביקריה כנ"ל. על ידי זה נעשה ג"כ מכובד ע"ד כי מכבדי אכבד. ויש לרמז זה גם כן בתנחומא (פ' זו ט) ל"ו דורות מאדם עד יעבץ ולא כתיב בא' מהן כבוד אלא ביעבץ דכ' ויהי יעבץ נכבד מאחיו כו' והיינו שהוא היה הראשון בעולם שלמד התורה ביגיעה שהוא החזיר בפילפולו ההלכות שנשתכחו באבלו של משה ולזה נקרא יעבץ שיעץ וריבץ תורה בישראל (כמ"ש תמורה טז.) והיינו שורש תורה שבעל פה שנצרך ליגיעה רבה כדי להיות חקוקה על לב האבן וכמ"ש (מגילה ו :) אלמלא חטאו ישראל לא ניתן להם אלא ה' חומשי תורה כו' כי ברוב חכמה רוב כעס שלתקן הרב כעס שיוחקקו הדברי תורה על לב אבן נצרך רב חכמה. ונאמר בו ואמו קראה שמו יעבץ לאמר כי ילדתי בעוצב והיינו שהרגישה בזה שהיה לה עצב וצער לידה ביותר שהוא מסיבת קלקול הראשון שנאמר אז בעצב תלדי בנים ומזה שערה בנפשה שנצרך לצאת מזה נפש יקרה שיכניע את הקליפות ועל ידי זה יש עליו ההתגברות מההיפך עדש"נ אשר שלט האדם באדם לרע לו. ועל ידי תיקון הרב כעס זוכין לכבוד כש"נ נכבדת כנ"ל. ועל זה מרמזים תיבות ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי להמשיך הקדושה ועל התעוררת האדם בנפשו לתקן הקלקול בתוספת שבת דלית נהורא אלא ההוא דנפיק מגו חשוכא ופרשה ויכולו השמים וגו' הוא עצם יום השבת הופעת הקדושה מלעילא כש"נ בו ויברך את יום השביעי ויקדש אותו. ועל זה מתחילין בתפלה אתה קדשת כו' וכן כ' בתורתך ויכולו וגו' היינו שאנו מרגישים השפעת הקדושה דשבת הנשפע מלעילא. ואחר זה בקידוש היום שנאמר בקידוש היום שנאמר זכור לקדשו זוכריהו על היין אנו מתחילין ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר וגו' היינו שהתחלת התעוררות לקדושה נצרך להיות מצד האדם להמשיך על נפשו בעבודה ויגיעה לאהפכא חשוכא לנהורא ואח"ז אנחנו מרגישים השפעת הקדושה מלעילא בקידוש ויכולו וגו' עם על בחינת התעוררת העבודה מצד האדם וכמו שאומרים לפניו נעבוד ביראה ופחד ונודה לשמו כו' ומזה דייקא נולד השמחה בלב ולכן קידוש היום על היין דייקא דכ' ויין ישמח לבב אנוש:

And all of this is alluded to in the words (recalled and said at Kiddush of Shabbat night, ויהי ערב ויהי בוקר יום הששי) *And it was evening and it was morning, the sixth day*, as recalled above, that specifically through the *evening* (the transitional time at the end of the day when the sun begins to set and the sky starts to darken) and the darkness (full night after the appearance of three medium stars, that night and darkness are compared to the period of exile, like the Egyptian exile which preceded the Giving of the Torah), preparation is made for the aspect of *the sixth day*, which is the quality of *Tzaddik, Yesod Olam* (Yosef, son of Yaacov Avinu is referred to as *Yosef HaTzaddik*. The Egyptian exile actually began during the lifetime of Avraham Avinu which corresponds to the time of sundown at the end of the 5th day. The night of the 6th day corresponds with when Yosef actually descended into Egypt.). And their known discourse (Shabbat 88) that the Holy One, blessed be He teaches that the letter *Heh* of the word *HaShishi* (השישי) is in relation to the works of the days of creation (which preceded the sixth day).

That if Israel accepts the Torah, they (meaning everything created before the sixth day) will be maintained, that all the works of creation are dependent upon the sixth of Sivan (the day of) the giving of the Torah.

Meaning that then, the completion of the jewelry (or the repair from the damage caused by Adam HaRishon) will be finished like it says, *Engraved on the Tablets* (חרות על הלוחות, that *cherut* can mean either *engraved* or *free from*) *Free from the Angel of Death* (like it says in Shemot Rabbah, chapter 41), which is the *Yetzer HaRa*, like is said (in Bava Batra 16).

And since the degradation (the worship of the golden calf) was also then and the tablets were shattered, it said, *hew for yourself two stone tablets, like the first ones, etc.*. That also now they said (in chapter 6 of Avot) from this posuk, that one is not free, except someone who is engaged in Torah study. Because for a certainty, at the time of the Giving of the Torah it was like the beginning of Creation. That G-d made Adam HaRishon *True* (ישר meaning he was intended to live eternally and not die).

That at the time that Israel heard the utterance I (am the L-rd, your G-d, etc. Shemot 20:2), Torah study was wedged into their heart (like it says in Shir HaShirim Rabbah on the posuk, *Let Him kiss me...* Shir HaShirim 1:2).

And they were in a state of absolute perfection because the heart was continuously joined together with fear and love of Him, blessed be He and they didn't require tablets of stone. That all the words of the Torah were engraved upon their heart and the Yetzer HaRa was uprooted from their heart with the utterance, You will not have...(like it is written there in Shemot 20:3) etc.

Comment: English please? Even a summary?

Comment: Could you help me understand the meaning of all this? What does the context teach us exactly? Could you capture the essence of it, because I get lost in the words, and miss context (because it isn't structured well enough and explained well enough). While I do think it could be a great answer to my question and other questions that I have.